# Using C# Fluent Validation, is it possible to create custom error messages which state why specific members of collection fail?

Tags: c#, list, asynchronous, race-condition, fluentvalidation

I have the following model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Enpal.SalesforceCache.Utils.Swagger;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Enpal.SalesforceCache.Model.Salesforce.Generic
{
    public class SalesforceDataRequestParameters
    {
        [SwaggerIgnore]
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "consumingApplication")]
        public string ConsumingApplication { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "role")]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sObjectName")]
        public string SObjectName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "readableFieldNames")]
        public HashSet<string> ReadableFieldNames { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>();

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "writableFieldNames")]
        public HashSet<string> WritableFieldNames { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>();

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "indexedFieldNames")]
        public HashSet<string> IndexedFieldNames { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>();

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "canDeleteRecords")]
        public bool CanDeleteRecords { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "incrementalRefreshIntervalInMinutes")]
        public int? IncrementalRefreshIntervalInMinutes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fullRefreshIntervalInDays")]
        public int? FullRefreshIntervalInDays { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "retentionAfterLastSyncInDays")]
        public int? RetentionAfterLastSyncInDays { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "writeIntervalInMinutes")]
        public int? WriteIntervalInMinutes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deleteIntervalInMinutes")]
        public int? DeleteIntervalInMinutes { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and the following validation class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Enpal.Salesforce.Client;
using Enpal.SalesforceCache.Configuration;
using Enpal.SalesforceCache.Model.Salesforce.Generic;
using Enpal.SalesforceCache.Services;
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Enpal.SalesforceCache.Validators
{
    public class SalesforceDataRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<SalesforceDataRequestParameters>
    {
        private readonly SObjectDescriptionCache _sObjectFieldCache;

        public SalesforceDataRequestValidator(IOptions<RecurringJobsConfig> recurringJobsConfig, SObjectDescriptionCache sObjectFieldCache)
        {
            if (recurringJobsConfig is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(recurringJobsConfig));
            }

            _sObjectFieldCache = sObjectFieldCache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sObjectFieldCache));

            RecurringJobsConfig recurringJobsValues = recurringJobsConfig.Value;

            RuleFor(request => request.IncrementalRefreshIntervalInMinutes)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumIncrementalRefreshIntervalInMinutes)
                .When(request => request.IncrementalRefreshIntervalInMinutes != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.FullRefreshIntervalInDays)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumFullRefreshIntervalInDays)
                .When(request => request.FullRefreshIntervalInDays != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.RetentionAfterLastSyncInDays)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumRetentionAfterLastSyncInDays)
                .When(request => request.RetentionAfterLastSyncInDays != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.WriteIntervalInMinutes)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumWriteIntervalInMinutes)
                .When(request => request.WriteIntervalInMinutes != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.DeleteIntervalInMinutes)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumDeleteIntervalInMinutes)
                .When(request => request.DeleteIntervalInMinutes != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.SObjectName)
                .MustAsync(SObjectMustExist)
                .WithMessage("Invalid sObject name.");

            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllReadableFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage("Invalid readable field names.");

            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllWritableFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage("Invalid writable field names.");

            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllIndexedFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage("Invalid indexed field names.");
        }

        private async Task<bool> SObjectMustExist(string sObjectName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            (bool exists, _) = await GetFieldNames(sObjectName, cancellationToken);
            return exists;
        }

        private Task<bool> AllReadableFieldsMustExist(SalesforceDataRequestParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            AllMustExist(parameters.SObjectName, parameters.ReadableFieldNames, cancellationToken);

        private Task<bool> AllWritableFieldsMustExist(SalesforceDataRequestParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            AllMustExist(parameters.SObjectName, parameters.WritableFieldNames, cancellationToken);

        private Task<bool> AllIndexedFieldsMustExist(SalesforceDataRequestParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HashSet<string> indexFieldNames = parameters.IndexedFieldNames
                .SelectMany(x => x.Split(";"))
                .Select(x => x.Trim('-', '_'))
                .ToHashSet();

            return AllMustExist(parameters.SObjectName, indexFieldNames, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<bool> AllMustExist(string sObjectName, HashSet<string> inputFieldNames, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            (bool exists, IList<string> fieldNames) = await GetFieldNames(sObjectName, cancellationToken);
            return exists && inputFieldNames.All(x => fieldNames.Contains(x));
        }


        private async Task<(bool exists, IList<string> fieldNames)> GetFieldNames(string sObjectName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            IList<string> fieldNames;
            try
            {
                fieldNames = await _sObjectFieldCache.GetFieldNames(sObjectName, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (SalesforceClientException)
            {
                return (false, new List<string>());
            }

            return (fieldNames != null, fieldNames);
        }
    }
}
```

While this works, it is far too vague about why the values for `ReadableFieldNames`, `WritableFieldNames`, and `IndexedFieldNames` may cause the entire instance to fail validation.

I'd like to modify the lines like `.WithMessage("Invalid readable field names.");` to tell me *which* field names are causing it to fail.

I've attempted to fix this like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Enpal.Salesforce.Client;
using Enpal.SalesforceCache.Configuration;
using Enpal.SalesforceCache.Model.Salesforce.Generic;
using Enpal.SalesforceCache.Services;
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Enpal.SalesforceCache.Validators
{
    public class SalesforceDataRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<SalesforceDataRequestParameters>
    {
        private readonly SObjectDescriptionCache _sObjectFieldCache;

        private const string ReadableFields = "Readable Fields";
        private const string WritableFields = "Writable Fields";
        private const string IndexedFields = "Indexed Fields";

        private readonly Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> BadFieldsByPurposes = new();


        public SalesforceDataRequestValidator(IOptions<RecurringJobsConfig> recurringJobsConfig, SObjectDescriptionCache sObjectFieldCache)
        {
            if (recurringJobsConfig is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(recurringJobsConfig));
            }

            _sObjectFieldCache = sObjectFieldCache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sObjectFieldCache));

            RecurringJobsConfig recurringJobsValues = recurringJobsConfig.Value;

            RuleFor(request => request.IncrementalRefreshIntervalInMinutes)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumIncrementalRefreshIntervalInMinutes)
                .When(request => request.IncrementalRefreshIntervalInMinutes != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.FullRefreshIntervalInDays)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumFullRefreshIntervalInDays)
                .When(request => request.FullRefreshIntervalInDays != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.RetentionAfterLastSyncInDays)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumRetentionAfterLastSyncInDays)
                .When(request => request.RetentionAfterLastSyncInDays != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.WriteIntervalInMinutes)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumWriteIntervalInMinutes)
                .When(request => request.WriteIntervalInMinutes != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.DeleteIntervalInMinutes)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(recurringJobsValues.MinimumDeleteIntervalInMinutes)
                .When(request => request.DeleteIntervalInMinutes != null);

            RuleFor(request => request.SObjectName)
                .MustAsync(SObjectMustExist)
                .WithMessage("Invalid sObject name.");

            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllReadableFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage(CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(ReadableFields));

            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllWritableFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage(CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(WritableFields));

            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllIndexedFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage(CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(IndexedFields));
        }

        private async Task<bool> SObjectMustExist(string sObjectName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            (bool sObjectExists, _) = await GetFieldNames(sObjectName, cancellationToken);
            return sObjectExists;
        }

        private Task<bool> AllReadableFieldsMustExist(SalesforceDataRequestParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            AllMustExist(parameters.SObjectName, parameters.ReadableFieldNames, ReadableFields, cancellationToken);

        private Task<bool> AllWritableFieldsMustExist(SalesforceDataRequestParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            AllMustExist(parameters.SObjectName, parameters.WritableFieldNames, WritableFields, cancellationToken);

        private Task<bool> AllIndexedFieldsMustExist(SalesforceDataRequestParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HashSet<string> indexFieldNames = parameters.IndexedFieldNames
                .SelectMany(x => x.Split(";"))
                .Select(x => x.Trim('-', '_'))
                .ToHashSet();

            return AllMustExist(parameters.SObjectName, indexFieldNames, IndexedFields, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<bool> AllMustExist(string sObjectName, HashSet<string> inputFieldNames, string purpose, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            (bool sObjectExists, IList<string> fieldNames) = await GetFieldNames(sObjectName, cancellationToken);
            bool allExist = sObjectExists && inputFieldNames.All(x => fieldNames.Contains(x));

            if (!allExist)
            {
                BadFieldsByPurposes[purpose] = await GetBadFieldNames(sObjectName, inputFieldNames, cancellationToken);
            }
            return allExist;
        }


        private async Task<(bool sObjectExists, IList<string> fieldNames)> GetFieldNames(string sObjectName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            IList<string> fieldNames;
            try
            {
                fieldNames = await _sObjectFieldCache.GetFieldNames(sObjectName, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (SalesforceClientException)
            {
                return (false, new List<string>());
            }
            return (fieldNames != null, fieldNames);
        }

        private async Task<HashSet<string>> GetBadFieldNames(string sObjectName, HashSet<string> inputFieldNames, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            IList<string> fieldNames;
            try
            {
                fieldNames = await _sObjectFieldCache.GetFieldNames(sObjectName, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (SalesforceClientException)
            {
                return inputFieldNames;
            }

            return inputFieldNames.Where(x => !fieldNames.Contains(x))
                .ToHashSet();
        }

        private string CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(string purpose) =>
            $"Invalid {purpose} names: {string.Join(",", BadFieldsByPurposes[purpose])}";
    }
}
```

However, this does not work because the system will attempt to resolve `.WithMessage(CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(ReadableFields))` before `.MustAsync(AllReadableFieldsMustExist)` has populated `private readonly Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> BadFieldsByPurposes`, and so `BadFieldsByPurposes[purpose]` will "blow up".

While WithMessage has some overloads, none seem to allow me to do anything async.

Is there any way I can make this work without ditching Fluent Validation?

(Or if I need to ditch the Fluent Validation, what might be the best way to do this?)

Answer (score 1):

This works, but I'm not sure it is a good solution:

```
            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllReadableFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage(x => CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(x.SObjectName, x.ReadableFieldNames, ReadableFields));

            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllWritableFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage(x => CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(x.SObjectName, x.WritableFieldNames, WritableFields));

            RuleFor(request => request)
                .MustAsync(AllIndexedFieldsMustExist)
                .WithMessage(x => CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(x.SObjectName, x.IndexedFieldNames, IndexedFields));
```

```
private string CreateFieldNameErrorMessage(string sObjectName, HashSet<string> inputFieldNames, string purpose)
        {
            Task<HashSet<string>> badFieldNames = GetBadFieldNames(sObjectName, inputFieldNames, default);
            HashSet<string> result = badFieldNames.Result;

            return $"Invalid {purpose} names: {string.Join(",", result)}.";
        }

        private async Task<HashSet<string>> GetBadFieldNames(string sObjectName, HashSet<string> inputFieldNames, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            IList<string> fieldNames;
            try
            {
                fieldNames = await _sObjectFieldCache.GetFieldNames(sObjectName, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (SalesforceClientException)
            {
                return inputFieldNames;
            }

            return inputFieldNames.Where(x => !fieldNames.Contains(x))
                .ToHashSet();
        }
```

I'm a little concerned because I'm not using `await` in `CreateFieldNameErrorMessage`, so I'm not sure how safe this is.

On the other hand, I've checked and thelogic to create this message is not executed if it is not needed.